# Получение ссылки на аудио из видео на ютубе и отправка аудио в телеграмм

Tags: python, aiogram, youtube

Пишу бота для скачивания музыки с ютуба. Есть ли возможность получить ссылку на аудио? Можно ли отправить это аудио через aiogram не скачивая его?

Comment: чтобы получить ссылку можно попробовать использовать youtube-dl --get-url,  насчёт aiogram не знаю ничего.

Comment: @xmikex мне нужно использовать это в питоне и получить ссылку на аудиофайл

Comment: ну запусти в пайпе youtube-dl и получи ответ.

Comment: from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

output = Popen(['command-to-run', 'some-argument'], stdout=PIPE)

Answer (score 0):

В python есть библиотеки, сам писал бота для этого @Download_Musik_bot
Библиотеки: pytube и search-youtube-python.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/725486)